# how client-side validation check it yii 2.0 advanced template

Tags: php, yii

I want client side validation in yii 2.0 advanced template

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'product_image1')->fileInput(['maxlength' => true,]) ?>
```

I want to check fileInput select file or not in client side validation

Answer (score 2):

In yii for any type of validation, you have to set validation rules in relative active form's Model.

> please check [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html)
>
> for file validation, please check [this](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/validation-rules-for-model-attributes-in-yiiframework-2-0/#yii2_file_type_validation)

Comment: thank  you but i want  js validation not rules based i know rules base validation but my application required js validation